# MemoryError while working with Nginx Server

Tags: python, django, server

**after reset code from the repository, I am running python manage.py makemigrations app_name, I got that issue. I am new to the Nginx server
So please help
Thanks in advance
**

Comment: running manage.py has nothing to do with nginx. It is or should be run on the console.
Please clarify your setup and what you've tried.

Comment: First thankyou @normic  Before these updation it's working fine after fetching code from the repository it's showes above error, and also tried revert previous commit then also it's working fine.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is, can you post the exact error message?

Comment: **MemoryError** I got, But Finally, After **stopping** the server then I run makemigrations and migrate. It's run fine the issue is resolved. Thanks, Mr **normic**